# Passing parameters to BCP command in SSIS execute SQL task

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, bcp

First of all, can i pass parameters for Path in BCP command?

I wrote this query in Exec SQL task

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM TLC.dbo.World_Hosts" queryout `"C:\Users\akshay.kapila\Desktop\TLC\Foreachlearn\Dest\?.txt" -T -c -t '`
```

I have given ? in path. I want specific countries in place of that. They are held in variable "Country".I am using Foreach loop which creates rather it should create a file ex Aus.txt,In.txt everytime loop runs for that specific value.

Can i use this way. If not, how can i pass variable value to Path in BCP command?

Answer (score 1):

You can use variable as the SQLSourceType in your Execute SQL Task.

Create a variable to hold your bcp command, it may look like:

```
"EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp \"SELECT ''abc'' as output\" queryout \"" + @[User::strFileName] + "\" -T -c -t '"
```

Here @[User::strFileName] is the dynamic file you want to generate.

Then in the Execute SQL Task, change SQLSourceType to variable, and select the variable you just generated.